# Android dynamic buttons - different amount in each row

Tags: android, button, dynamic

I am trying to add different number of buttons in each row. Say a random number of buttons in each row. The number of rows is a constant defined. I watched some tutorials and so far have the below code. This produces the same number of buttons in each row. Can you please help? Thank you.

```
private void populateButtons() { 
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.button); 
    for (int row = 0; row != NUM_ROWS; row++) { 
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
        table.addView(tableRow);
        for (int col = 0; col != NUM_COLS; col++){ 
            final int FINAL_COL = col; 
            final int FINAL_ROW = row; 
            Button button = new Button(this); 
            button.setLayoutParams(
                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f)); 
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            tableRow.addView(button); 
            buttons[row][col] = button; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest, create chips TextView and make them click able.

Comment: ok, do you by any chance have some example code? Thank you

Comment: Easiest one https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library. There are others too. Usually this concept is used in EditText but you can implement the same for TextView too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using same value for NUM_COLS.

If you want to add different number of buttons in each row , so you should define number of buttons for each row like this..

int [] NUM_COLS = {2, 3,4};

and your code will be like this

```
private void populateButtons() { 
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.button); 
for (int row = 0; row != NUM_ROWS; row++) { 
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    for (int row = 0; row != NUM_ROWS; row++) { 
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
        tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        table.addView(tableRow);
        for (int col = 0; col != NUM_COLS[row]; col++){ 
            final int FINAL_COL = col; 
            final int FINAL_ROW = row; 
            Button button = new Button(this); 
            button.setLayoutParams(
                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0f)); 
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        tableRow.addView(button); 
        buttons[row][col] = button; 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, perfect. This works great. I now have rows with different number of columns. I set the button params to button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 250));

Comment: The problem now is that the button rows are not centered. If I have for instance 3 in the first row but 4 in the next, the top row matches with the second column. Is there a way to center each tableRow to center inside of parent (TableLayout)? Also, if I generate more buttons with the current fixed size, they go off the screen, can I have the buttons match parent but each row not stretch? Please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess I am trying to center the buttons in each row so that they are center on the screen (left-right).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "random" quantity. You need to know what is the maximum quantity of buttons you could have and what could be their icon and text. There best way that come to my mind is to have each button in a layout xml with its id, icon, styles and description.

In the ListAdapter onCreateView method you need to have some logic that says, hey in this item I need to add the button Save and Edit, but maybe in another row the View, Edit and Remove e.g. and you will need to inflate those button layouts and add them into a container within the list item layout.

**NOTE:** If you also will support that the user can press onto the list row, you will need to add to each button `android:focusable="false"`, otherwise you will have focus problems.

Next step is to implement an interface with all the possible button actions, which each one of them will receive as the only parameter an entry from ListAdapter (Suppose your adapter extends from ArrayAdapter, each action method would receive a Video object) and your Fragment needs to implement this interface and when you instantiate the Adapter you need to pass the Fragment instance (you could use simply this or a member instance).

Last step from the ListAdapter you need to set the onClickListener to the interface action method that correspond with the button. You will manage each action from the Fragment knowing which item has been pressed.

Comment: ok, yes, this is good explanation. So focusable is when the user can see the button is selected?

Comment: Objects that are focusable true by default takes the focus to them. In a list item, what happen is that when the user press onto the list item, it does nothing because other objects in the list item have the focus.